# Exporting dll functions to unmanaged programs

Tags: c#

How can I export my c# dll functions to be able to use them from unmanaged programs.

- For example : Dll in c# and the application in Delphi/c++ .

I don't have the source of the exe because is not Open S.
Can't use COM.

Comment: Had some problems with that Nuget and found quite easy way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225277/how-to-call-managed-code-from-unmanaged-code/68692560#68692560

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using Robert Giesecke's [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

Comment: I'm constantly amused that this question gets asked repeatedly and always gets a different answer :\

Comment: @Michael It always gets the same answer from me.

Comment: The problem is this gets asked so often that the same people rarely see it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812338/reverse-pinvoke-and-create-a-full-unmanaged-c-sharp-program, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225277/calling-managed-code-from-unmanaged-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821109/calling-managed-code-from-unmanaged-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635679/how-to-use-managed-code-from-unmanaged-code

Comment: Your answer, BTW, is easily the "best"; maybe you should go add it to the rest of the list :)

Comment: Still waiting for an answer that explains how it works.  Without that, you'll never know when it *stops* working or how expensive it is.  Those stubs certainly are not cheap.  Giesecke prefers to be mysterious, more fun that way.

Comment: @HansPassant: You have have found out in the over 2 years since that comment, but if not, It works using the the frameworks reverse P/Invoke support. (This makes your assembly platform-specific.) Basically in IL you can add `.export [1]` to a method to export a method in slot one of the unmanaged export table. A marshaling thunk gets generated at runtime. Use the normal marshaling attributes like you would with forward P/Invoke to customize the effective native signature. The `.export` clause also takes an optional 'as exported_name' clause to allow you to set the name in the export table.

Comment: @HansPassant: (Continued). Chapter 18 of "Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler" describes this is slightly more detail, although I suspect better books exist.

Comment: Sure, I just use C++/CLI to accomplish the exact same thing.  It just takes __declspec(dllexport).  I can set a breakpoint on it.