# Unable to compile managed c# code within unmanaged c++ code using cli layer

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am doing a POC where I need to invoke a c# method from a c++ application.
So I did the following:

1. Create a c# library.
2. Create a c++/cli library wrapping the dll from step 1.
3. Creating a c++ library that would consume cli wrapper.
4. Creating an unmanaged console application that would use c++ dll output from step 3.

Guys,
I have done a lot of searches in last days but did not get any useful help.

1. Created the c# project with output: DotNetLogger.dll
2. Created the c++/cli project with output: CliLogger.dll
   Also referenced DotNetLogger.dll
   Also exported a method.
3. Create C++ project with output CppLogger.dll
   and so on.

Also,
C# project setting:  v4.6.2
C++/CLI project settings:  /CLR enabled with v4.6.2
C++ project setting: no /clr

```
namespace DotNetLogger
{
    public class ManagedLogger
    {
        public void Ping()
        {
          //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

```
using namespace System;
using namespace DotNetLogger;

namespace CliLogger {
    public ref class LoggerBridge
    {
    public:
        ManagedLogger^ obj;
        LoggerBridge() {
            obj = gcnew ManagedLogger();
        }
        void Result() {
            return obj->Ping();
        }
    };
}

__declspec(dllexport) void AreYouThere() {
    CliLogger::LoggerBridge obj;
    return obj.Result();
}
```

```
#pragma once

#include "D:\Logger_POC_NoWorks\InteropLogger\CliLogger\CliLogger.h"

__declspec(dllimport) void AreYouThere();

class UnmanagedLogger {
public:
    void InvokeResult() {
        return AreYouThere();
    }
};
```

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "D:\Logger_POC_NoWorks\InteropLogger\CppLogger\CppLogger.h"


int main()
{
    UnmanagedLogger uLogger;
    uLogger.InvokeResult();
}
```

Expected Result:
The console application shall build successfully in VS 2017.

But I am getting compiler errors;

1. `Warning   C4273   'AreYouThere': inconsistent dll linkage ServiceCode d:\logger_poc_noworks\interoplogger\cpplogger\cpplogger.h   5`
2. `Error C2871   'DotNetLogger': a namespace with this name does not exist   ServiceCode d:\logger_poc_noworks\interoplogger\clilogger\clilogger.h   4`
3. `Error C2039   'LoggerBridge': is not a member of 'CliLogger'  ServiceCode d:\logger_poc_noworks\interoplogger\clilogger\clilogger.h   21`

And many cascading errors.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647766/exporting-dll-functions-to-unmanaged-programs

Comment: `#include "D:\Logger_POC_NoWorks\InteropLogger\CppLogger\CppLogger.h"` – don't use absolute include paths in source code, instead just use the relative part in code `#include "CppLogger\CppLogger.h"` and specify the include path appropriately in project settings (preferrably as relative path to project location, there should be a variable for). Otherwise you'd need to change code any time you move your project (or other's would have to, if you share code with them).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your second block of code is `clilogger.h`?

You don't need to include `cliLogger.h` in your 3rd block of code as you are only using `AreYouThere` which you have already declared, this declaration also conflicts with the declaration from the header (hence the `inconsistent dll linkage` warning). This header also contains CLI code which will produce errors in your pure c++ file (probably the cause of your `'LoggerBridge': is not a member of 'CliLogger'` error).

Answer (score 0):

The `#include` directive is resolved by the pre-processor, which just is a pure text processor unaware of actual C++ (or C) semantics. So this piece of code

```
#include "D:\Logger_POC_NoWorks\InteropLogger\CliLogger\CliLogger.h"

__declspec(dllimport) void AreYouThere();

class UnmanagedLogger { /* ... */ }
```

will result in

```
using namespace System;
using namespace DotNetLogger;

namespace CliLogger { /* ... */ }

__declspec(dllexport) void AreYouThere()
{
    CliLogger::LoggerBridge obj;
    return obj.Result();
}

__declspec(dllimport) void AreYouThere();

class UnmanagedLogger { /* ... */ }
```

being presented to compiler after pre-processing, which will result in two problems:

1. Unmanaged compiler still sees managed code (e. g. `public ref class LoggerBridge`, which is invalid in pure unmanaged C++).
2. You get the incompatible declaration of `AreYouThere`, first with `dllexport`, then second time with `dllimport`.

So you need a separate header only containing unmanaged code and managing the import/export problem.

Typically, you'd have something like:

```
#ifdef INSIDE_MY_DLL_IMPLEMENTATION // invent up some better name yourself...
#define DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_IMPORT void areYouThere();
```

In referencing project, you'd just include the header then, inside DLL code, you'd have instead:

```
#define INSIDE_MY_DLL_IMPLEMENTATION // must precede, of course...
#include "new_interface_file.h"
```

---

Generalising now: You can use this pattern for any DLL, managed or purely unmanaged alike. For the latter case, you could even consider different compilers (e. g. `__attribute__((dllimport))` for GCC, although you might need some extra work as GCC attributes don't precede, but follow function declaration). Solely: different C++ implementations (compilers) most likely come with incompatible ABI, so you should fall back to a pure C interface if you plan multiple compiler compatibility:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

// ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks Aconcagua for the detailed information. Also, I clearly understood the reasons behind those issues.However, I do have one doubt about having a seperate header for exporting the functions. Does the header to export the functions remain in CLI project or shall I make a seperate project? My bet on CLI but still want to confirm once?

Comment: Why en extra project? Consider your DLL some product, then the header is part of, like the manuals for a washing machine. So I'd keep the header together with the rest of the dll. You might organize everything in sub folders, though.